# Java POJO file null value change to default predefined value

Tags: java, spring, maven

This is my POJO file which am using
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` for remove Null value.

here `"university" : "" -` empty value

current output,(jackson removed that field)

```
{ "id" : 1, "user_id" : 1, "education" : "s adfsdsd fsdfad", "institute" : "fsdf", "date_from" : "2014-01-01 00:00:00.0", "date_to" : "2011-03-01 00:00:00.0" }
```

**but i need output like**(instead of null i need- not_defined)

```
{ "id" : 1, "user_id" : 1, "education" : "s adfsdsd fsdfad", "institute" : "fsdf", **"university" : "not_defined"**, "date_from" : "2014-01-01 00:00:00.0", "date_to" : "2011-03-01 00:00:00.0" }


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

/**
 * Created by gopu on 18/3/16.
 */
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class UserEducation {

    private long id;
    private int user_id;
    private String education, institute, university, date_from, date_to;

    public UserEducation(long id, int user_id,  String education, String institute, String university, String date_from, String date_to) {
        this.id = id;
```

Comment: That looks like an awful idea to me. The presentation layer should take care of displaying "not defined" if there is no university in the data. The JSON shouldn't take care of that. But anyway, what is the question/problem? Why don't you just initialize the field in the POJO to "not_defined"?

Comment: actually i need to replace all null value from SQL call with "not_defined" instead of "NULL" on json output

Comment: Now you're bringing the persistence layer, in addition to the communication layer and the presentation layer to the table. As I said, don't mix these aspects together. Keep your database and JSON clean, and let the presentation layer deal with displaying "not defined" if the field is null. Again, that said, where is the problem? If the university column is null in the database, then leave the university field in the JSON to its default value ("not_defined"), or explicitly set it to "not_defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own `JsonSerializer` to accomplish this:

```
class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        gen.writeString("not_defined");
    }
}
```

And then annotate your field to use it:

```
@JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = MySerializer.class)
private String university;
```

By defining `nullsUsing` you make sure your custom serializer is only called for `null` values and only for the annotated field(s).

Btw, annotating your class with `@JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = MySerializer.class)` will not work - see the `JsonSerialize` docs for details.